# My Project could not able to view in online

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

My project is not working in online  (cpanel)
     "https://www.sample.com/folder"

But i give my url like this means working
    "https://www.sample.com/folder/index.php/controller_name"

i want like "***sample.com/folder/controller_name***"

how to resolve this. I want my URL like above the first one

My Config file information

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

my Route file like this, Is here any Problem.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/home";
$username = '(:any)';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['sample/([0-9]+)'] = "sample/index/$1";
$route['pages/profile'] = "pages/profile"; 
$route['pages/userList'] = "pages/userList";
$route['auth/logout'] = "auth/logout";
$route['auth'] = "auth/logout";
$route['auth/login'] = "auth/login";
$route['auth/register'] = "auth/register";
$route['pages/post'] = "pages/post";
```

Comment: This does not look like a development question and you are providing far to little information. You might want to ask your question on serverfault.com

Comment: added regarding url details @Quasimodo's clone

Answer (score 0):

first you change in your config.php

```
 $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

To

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

change

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.sample.com/';
```

and your HTACCESS file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: you also change your htaccess file

Comment: change your $config['base_url'] = 'https://www.sample.com/'; in your config.php file

Comment: enable mod_rewrite in Apache

Comment: Sorry, Nothing Works @Aslam , krishnakumar

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.htaccess` file at "https://www.sample.com/folder" to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: where to place the .htacess file.. either under the domain (sample.com) or under (sample.com/folder)

Comment: is necessary .htacess in under (https.www.sample.com) ?

Comment: Put `.htaccess` file in `(sample.com/folder)` @JanaSan

Comment: tried Not worked @jatin . Now I was check mod_rewrite in my linux server, But it does not shown (How to enable that?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2 Hope this will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your config file you need to change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

then change

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.sample.com/folder/';
//you need to put the folder
```

then in your .htacces //put it in root path like /var/www/foler/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Again i tried this above but nothing happen. I am in that same position